# Backbone LayoutManager Rendering Collection View's models in batches

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, client

For one part of my backbone application, certain json responses can return up to 4000 images.  Obviously, I don't want to render ALL those into the DOM.

I'm using backbone.layoutmanager, but I'm struggling with a way to render a collection's views in batches of say 50 - 100, and the then render the rest as the user scrolls.  Is there way to do this without having to override layoutmanager's implementation of `render`?

Answer (score 0):

here is something that you can use. it will surely solve your problem.
https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.